# Firefox SwPush not subscribing

Tags: angular

I have the following code in my app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() : void{
    this.subscribeToNotifications();

    
  }
    
  subscribeToNotifications() {
    this.swPush.requestSubscription({
      serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
    })
      .then(pushSubscription => {
        console.log(pushSubscription);
        // Passing subscription object to our backend
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      })
  }
```

Upon launching my application in Firefox the function doesn't log anything, but when using Chrome it does. How can I make this work in Firefox too?

Comment: could you specify your `firefox` version?

Comment: @sonkatamas 80.0.1

Comment: with `debugging` or `logging` could you check the `value` of `swPush`?

Comment: please check out this similar issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30552